# How can I configure my program to run in a loop?

Tags: java, eclipse, shell

How can I configure my Java program to run in a loop? I have written a code in Unix Shell Script and it's working fine.

Here is the code written in unix:

```
if [ "$1" != "ALL" ]
then
while [ "$i" -le $1 ]
do
java -cp $BATCHCLASSPATH -Dbootstrap.system.propertiespath=/home/wlc1212/15AUNIXDEV/SpringBatch/properties -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.tcs.wstest.Test $FILPATH/$2Input_$i.xml $FILPATH/$2Output_$i.xml $i
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
fi

// $1 can be 1 or 2 or n
```

Now I want to run it in a same way but in Eclipse. Is there any way to run my program in the same way in Eclipse? How can I set a loop?

Comment: If any one have an idea about this. Please share.

Comment: Does not directly answer your question, but you could also make the loop and related functionality part of the Java program, which would also have the advantage of not having to start a new JVM for every iteration.

Comment: Thanks Arkku.. I think I got what you are saying.. The loop part I can configure in my java program itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse Luna and probably other Eclipse versions, an external script can be run by creating a run configuration for it in Run/External Tools/External Tools Configurations. In the latter's window create a new launch configuration with absolute pathname of your external shell such as bash in the Location field and the absolute pathname of your bash script in the Arguments field. The Working Directory field can be whatever is appropriate for your script in case it needs to read or write data to certain files.

This does not have the capability to automatically rerun the script but 
you have already coded it with a loop so its not necessary to do that externally.

Another typical way to repeat execution of a script on Unix/Linux systems is to use cron or "at" and both can be configured at user level.  This may be preferable in order to run the script at fixed time intervals provided the runtimes will be reasonably bounded. The cron or "at" job could run your java command directly or it could run another script written to check that your java application is not running before launching it again.